# How to replace characters inside bracket with word matching

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have bunch of c files containing a particular variable defined in many files. I need find and replace that variable. 
For example:

```
U2 xyz[abc],    //comment
```

i want to find the word [abc], and add an extra space after a comma, by which it will increase a space before //comment.

```
U2 xyz[abc], //comment
```

will be replaced as

```
U2 xyz[abc],    //comment
```

I tried with following command:

```
sed -i 's/\b/[abc/]/,\b/[abc/],/  /g' *  (with escape)
sed -i 's/\b[abc],\b/[abc],  /g' *
sed -i 's/\[abc\],\[abc], /g' tst1.cpp    (This works fine without \b word matching)
```

How do i do it?

Comment: Please add some examples of input and desired output. At the moment I understand that you want to insert a space between `,` and `//`, independent of brackets, words and whole words.

Comment: The default `sed` uses BREs (Basic Regular Expressions), you need to use EREs (Extended Regular Expressions), that's the `-E` option.  Also be aware that not all `sed's` support`\b`.